# Updating apache2 keys, ssl validation fail on apache2 start

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I got a new set of keys for my apache2 server, the old ones expired, and I'm at a loss how to troubleshoot.

I tried to just copy the new keys to the keystore at `/etc/ssl/` and rewrote the paths directives in the apache2 conf.

```
    SSLEngine On
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/serv.er.tld.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/serv.er.tld.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/chain-thisisanumber-serv.er.tld.pem
```

What i get is

```
Unable to configure RSA server private key
SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate
routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

The new set is similar to the old one but it has a few more files. Do I need to reference these in any way?

For instance one of the files is

```
chain-thisisanumber-serv.er.tld-3-AddTrust_External_CA_Root.pem
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't have two VirtualHosts using different keys.**

The problem was in another virtual host using another set of keys. This is apparently a no-no.  Also it fails silently, no error message in either of the hosts log-files.

Answer (score 1):

Your key and cert are a key pair. You shouldn't get new keys without new certs. You can get a new cert without a new key. That depends on if you used your existing key to create the new cert request. Make sure you're updating your certs at the same time. As for your chain file, I'd check the md5sum and if it differes from your existing SSLCertificateChainFile I'd back up the old one and replace it with the new one. I hope this helps!

Comment: Both cert and key are new for me. I did not request the new certs from a CA, but rather an IT department. Still; it is likely the main keys are the same.  What does the chain files do? I have a total of 4 chain files. The apache docs are unclear on the subject.

Comment: I dug this command up for you. It will give us more insight to your problem.

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/ssl/certs/serv.er.tld.pem`
`openssl rsa -noout -text -in /etc/ssl/private/serv.er.tld.key`

From the first command check that the cert's Modulus matches the keys's modulus from the second command. If they differ there is a problem with your key pair. Obviously you shouldn't post the output since it holds the cryptographics used in your cert!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I did try them already, and they passed.  From http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-fix-common-ssl-errors.htm

Comment: Apparently the modulus can match but the keys can still be invalid. This person says they got the the person who issued their cert to give them the cert in a format that contained both the cert and the key. You can convert a cert using the openssl cli. It would ensure that the person who sent you the cert didn't accidentally it. Good luck, it sounds like you have a gremlin! From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658484/ssl-install-problem-key-value-mismatch-but-they-do-match

Comment: Gremlin is not likely, user error is a lot more probable.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Did you solve your problem? If so can you post your answer to your own question?

Comment: Yes I did solve it.